# Fetch Data from two different entity in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9

I have 2 entity("Achievement" and "ShortTermGoal") as shown in Screenshot.

I am fetching data from Achievement entity where

```
shortTermSubGoalId = "PROVIDED_ID"
```

Now i want to get `shortTermGoalName` also from `ShortTermGoal` entity where `shortTermSubGoalId = "SAME_AS_PROVIDED_ABOVE"`.

I want `NSManagedObject` Should contain all data from Achievement entity and `shortTermGoalName` from `ShortTermGoal` entity(each object of `NSManagedObject` will have all properties of "Achievement" + `shortTermGoalName` Property of `ShortTermGoal` entity).

It it possible? 
if yes then how?

Please share code snippet.

**Achievement Entity**

[image: Achievement]

**ShortTermGoal Entity**

[image: ShortTermGoal]

Answer (score 0):

You can only get instances of `NSManagedObject` that correspond exactly to a specific Core Data entity. They don't compose properties from multiple entities into a single `NSManagedObject` instance. This is just one of the ways in which Core Data does not work like SQL-- you're not fetching a table of results, you're fetching model objects directly.

Core Data has a different way of handling this, via the relationships you have configured.

If you fetch instances of `Achievement`, you'll get all of the properties of that entity. You can also access all of the properties of the related `ShortTermGoal` entity by using the `shortTermGoal` relationship you already have. You get the value of `shortTermGoalName` in one of a couple of ways:

- If you *have* created custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses for your entities, then if you have an `Achievement`,

  ```
  let achievement : Achievement = // Created somewhere else
  let name = achievement.shortTermGoal?.shortTermGoalName
  ```
- If you *have not* created custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses for your entities, then if you have an `NSManagedObject` corresponding to an `Achievement`,

  ```
  let achievement : NSManagedObject = // Created somewhere else
  let name = achievement.valueForKeyPath("shortTermGoal.shortTermGoalName")
  ```

Note that this assumes you have actually assigned a value to the `shortTermGoal` relationship.

Comment: i am trying to get value for KeyPath "shortTermGoal.shortTermGoalName" but i am not getting any value.

Comment: po obj.valueForKeyPath("shortTermGoal.shortTermGoalName")
nil

Comment: Did you ever set a value for the relationship? That's what I said in the last line of the answer-- this only works if you assign a value for the relationship in the first place.